# Update whole table records where column have specific value

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project in which a table has lot of records. most of the rows have 0 or empty record in column. Its not possible to update all manually or by writing query for each row or column. 
Is there efficient way by which i can replace 0's by empty or empty by 0's and one more things..
Some columns have ",0" and "0," which also have to be replaced. here is screenshot of data in screenshot to give idea.. http://prntscr.com/8rvn67

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't access the screenshot. Howver, the general solution could be to list the values to be replaced in an IN() clause, if the list is small

```
update table set fieldname='0' where fieldname in ('',',0','0,")
```

Comment: Problem is same that i have to be excute this query for all columns. but is there any way that all this done in one query?

Comment: If for each column you want to cleanse you need a different where condition, then no, you can't do it in one query.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow i am doing it column by column.

Answer (score 0):

To remove those `0`,`,0` to empty space `''` you need to use next query

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column = REPLACE(column, '0', '')
WHERE column  LIKE '%0%'
```

Hope it helps